# Photoshop ico files and mass exporting issues

Tags: photoshop-scripting

I'm using http://telegraphics.com.au/sw/ 's ico plugin to easily load ico files in photoshop(vs converting to png first)... This made it easier to use ico files.

I have a custom .NET exporting program that works fine EXCEPT when it tries to save layers to disk, when it comes across some layers, the ico plugin pops up telling me "Choose icon - the ico file contains 7 icons" etc. The same thing when you import an ico file.

This breaks the work flow and doesn't even export it properly since I've manipulated the ico by applying effects and rasterization.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had some ico's in a folder and it seems if one has any ico in the project that the ico plugin will pop up for export options at some point depending on what is called(in my case, doc.Trim()). It only does this once after project load. My script was ignoring all the ico files I had so I thought it shouldn't matter. Seems to be some kind of initialization issue with the plugin.

Ultimately rasterizing all imported ico's is the solution. Any lingering ico files will trigger the plugin and break the flow.